# How to create a web server using android studio?

Tags: android, web, android-studio

I want to send some data collected by the app to the computer through internet. And secondly, apart from this, want to show live feed of the camera on the computer via internet.

I think making a web server will be a good option for the first requirement. But as I am new to android development, so please guide me.

For the live feed option, please suggest how this can be acheived.

Comment: Will your Android device be connected to the same network that the computer is connected to? What OS is your computer running?

Comment: Where is your device? To which computer? Why do you need internet? Where should the web server run? On your device? On a PC? If not on an Android device then why do you want to use Android Studio to make that web server? Your story is very unclear.

Comment: albinobat Yes my android will be connected to the same network as the computer. The computer will be running windows.

@greenapps My device is somewhere near the computer such that they are on the same lan. The web server should run on device, responding to all the requests made by the computer.

Please ask for any other detail.

Comment: `want to send some data collected by the app to the computer through internet`. Repeat:  `Why do you need internet?`

Comment: The app I am trying to build is taking all the readings from all the available sensors on the mobile. Now I want these readings to be available to me through Wi-Fi wirelessly. For this purpose I want to make a webserver on the mobile, so whenever I want to see the readings, I just have to enter the webserver ip on my laptop to see them.

Now there maybe many mistakes in my mistake as I am completely new to all this. Please guide me if I am going down a wrong path.

Comment: You did not use the word internet in your explanation. So how could this be an answer?

Comment: Please see this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358190/how-to-host-rest-api-server-in-android-application-using-jersey/59379434#59379434](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358190/how-to-host-rest-api-server-in-android-application-using-jersey/59379434#59379434)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure if this is good idea if you are new to android. Maybe start with something easier but if you do plan to do it any way.

To send data collected by the app you will have to send it to some kind of backend you will have to make it i suggest making it in PHP and saving the data in a Mysql database.

For the sending part you will probably want to do it in the background with a AsyncTask and it will look something like this :

```
public class Backend extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String server = "http://example.com/foo/bar"
    String uid = params[0];
    String name = params[1];
    String email = params[2];

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(server+"NewUser.php");


    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));

    try {
        // Probeer dat te zetten
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        // Execute
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Zet response om naar String
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        return responseBody;

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "0";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "0";
    }
}

}
```

And you can execute this class like this:

```
new Backend().execute("1","maantje","email@example.com")
```

This will now POST uid, email, name to example.com/foo/bar/NewUser.php
So you will have to create that the data will be in $_POST['uid],$_POST['email'] and $_POST['name'].

Also don't forget the internet permissions in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

For the live feed option i have no experience with that but maybe this is a good place to start https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

Comment: Your awesome post was sent in 2015. I don't know how much was changed since than. I am trying to convert the Simon Monk HomeAutomation https://github.com/simonmonk/arduino-android/blob/master/Android%20Binaries/HomeAutomation.apk to fit the new Android Standards, using Android Studio but I am having trouble with the
URL = startWebServer();//Problema com essa linha de código
line code. Debuging it, write the line before, the program is ok, and after, it stops.

Maybe you could help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. You need server which can handle your request from phone. Basically you need web-service which is called api. You can create those api by using java,node.js etc and you need database to store your data. For database purpose, you can use MongoDB or any other database.

Your api will handle POST request to hold the data from user request from the app. This is how, you can hold user data. 
For live feed of the camera, I am not sure. Expecting to hear from some expert guys. Thanks and best of luck